# From Vagrant Vbox using Redis, setting up localhost on Host

Tags: redis, localhost, vagrant

I'm setting up a development environment.  I'm trying a number of technologies for the first time.  I'm using a vagrant installation of Ubuntu, and I installed a site using Django-Heroku-Bootstrap.  It's using Redis as a broker for Celery, which in turn is used for running background tasks.  All of this deploys on Heroku, so that's great.  But I am having issues with my localhost.

The Vagrant machine was set up with

```
config.vm.forward_port 6379, 6379  # I added this for redis
config.vm.forward_port 8000, 8888  # the default
```

But when I go to localhost:6379 I get this:

```
-ERR wrong number of arguments for 'get' command
-ERR unknown command 'Host:'
-ERR unknown command 'Connection:'
-ERR unknown command 'Cache-Control:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept:'
-ERR unknown command 'User-Agent:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept-Encoding:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept-Language:'
-ERR unknown command 'Accept-Charset:'
-ERR unknown command 'Cookie:'
-ERR unknown command 'DNT:'
```

Does anyone know what the correct process is for setting up forward_port from a redis server on vagrant Vbox to allow me to use my host machine (Windows 7 x64) browser, localhost:{{ some_port }}

Thank you in advance,

Anthony

Comment: what happens when you try running redis-cli

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved.  I was forwarding the wrong port, the dev server running on vagrant was listening at port 5000, so when I forwarded that to something open on my local machine [config.vm.forward_port 5000, 5656] everything works fine.